# How to declare a list inside an entity in angular?

Tags: angular

I am a newie in angular and try to display a list of towns in a region.
This is my code:
`@Input() currentRegion: Region = { name: '', towns: new Town[]() };`

How to write the correct syntax?

Comment: There's some merit to each of fujy's and Bartłomiej Stasiak's replies.  I would do the following: 1) Create a [data module](https://angular-folder-structure.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html) and define types for `Region` and `Town`, 2) Declare `Region` objects like [Bartłomiej Stasiak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76740808/421195) suggested, 3) Iterate through the "towns" array in your "Region" object like [fujy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76740247/421195) suggested to process the data at runtime.  See [Working with models in Angular](https://nehalist.io/working-with-models-in-angular/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NgFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) directive to iterate over the list of towns

```
<li *ngFor="let town of currentRegion.towns">
  {{town.attribute1}} ... {{town.attribute2}} ....
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let change it. Definition of empty list:

```
@Input() currentRegion: Region = { 
    name: '', 
    towns: []
};
```

If you want to know, how to define list with some values:

```
@Input() currentRegion: Region = { 
    name: '', 
    towns: [{
        yourProp1: `some value`
    },{
        yourProp1: `some other value`
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of structural directive - [NgFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) to display the list.
But moreover need to check how you have declared your types or interfaces. For your reference I have given sample example below with syntax.

```js
interface Town {
  name : string;
  population : number;
}

interface Region {
  name : string;
  towns : Town[];
}

@Input()
currentRegion : Region = { 
  name = "Mumbai",
  towns = [
    { name : 'Andheri', population : 200000 },
    { name : 'Juhu', population : 100000 }
  ]
}
```

```html
<li *ngFor="let town of currentRegion.towns">{{ town.name }}</li>
```